# asp.net 5 upgrade from beta-4 to beta-6

Tags: asp.net, json, package, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my solution from beta-4 to beta-6 and I have a problem with 
Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json package because it is still beta-4 and If I remove it from project.json I get an error configBuilder does not contain a definition for AddJsonFile, if I leave it there IApplicationEnvironment is in 2 assemblies.
Is there a "how to upgrade" tutorial from b4 to b6?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this page?

Sounds like you might be missing the new VS tools which are required as part of Beta6.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/07/27/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta-6.aspx